# How to enter date as an option in a bash command?

Tags: bash, date, output

I want to enter the current date (ideally in the form YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm) as an option in a bash script:

I tried

```
/usr/local/bin/growlnotify -t "PMK" -m date
```

but then the variable -m inserts the string "date" in the output.
How can I tell the script that it has to use the output value of the "date" command?

(I'm using MacOS X 10.6 and the growlnotify command is used to display a popup window with 2 strings ("PMK" and a second one where I'd like to get the current date/time)
http://growl.info/ )

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/growlnotify -t "PMK" -m $(date "+%F %H:%M")`

Comment: thanks, as I already commented below, this strangely adds the time string after PMK (like PMK 12:08) and only the date is processed by the -m option. But it's ok for me for the moment, this must be something with the growlnotify command

Answer (score 6, accepted):

writing `date` as an argument to another command will not get you the output of that command, just the string you typed.

In bash you can insert the result from a command by including it in `$(  )`. That leaves that you need to specify form (format) that you want to get from `date`, and that can be deduced from `man date` (FORMAT section):

```
date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
```

This will give you a 24h clock (There are other ways to get this result, as Costas indicated, but this way you can easily change the characters between the year representation e.g. Germans often want `/`).

The full invocation would then be (there is no need to quote `PMK`, but don't forget the `$( ...)`):

```
/usr/local/bin/growlnotify -t PMK -m "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')"
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! In fact, your suggested answer (if I add the `$( ... )` ) strangely adds the time after "PMK" and only the date in the second line... but for the moment it's ok for me.

Comment: @Martin: Probably this is caused by the shell splitting the output of `date` at the space, which makes the time a separate argument to `growlnotify`. Try putting double quotes around: `"$(...)"`

Comment: Put the `$( ... )` part in double quotes: `"$( ... )"` otherwise the shell simply splits date's output at the space, just as if you had typed `-m 2014-10-31 13:22`

Comment: @Martin I did not only forgot the `$(...)` in the final line but, like  wurtel indictated, also double quotes around the whole to keep the space separated output together as one option argument for grwInotify.

Comment: great, now it works perfectly. :-)